# How do I perform a case-insensitive compare of GUIDs with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, asp.net-membership

In the code below, I want to compare two GUIDs. The problem is I don't get any tasks returned because the GUIDS are different case (uppercase vs. lowercase). I need to perform a case-insensitive compare.

```
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();
string strUserId = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

Guid userId = new Guid(strUserId.ToUpper());

lblUserId.Text = userId.ToString();

DataModelEntities dc = new DataModelEntities();

var userTasks = dc.tasks.Where(t => t.user_id == userId).ToList();
```

How do I compare the GUIDs and find matches regardless of case?

UPDATE 1
now coverting the guid out of the membership provider to a GUID

```
Guid userId = (Guid) membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

BUt I'm still not getting any matches.

Comment: Why are you comparing the GUIDs as strings instead of just as `System.Guid`?

Comment: @Matt - How do I cast to a GUID? I looked for a Convert.ToGuid (or something similar) but couldn't find anything.

Comment: you can use `Guid.Parse(...)`, `Guid.TryParse(...)` or `Guid.TryParseExact(...)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure why you're comparing them as text, but instead of `t.user_id == userId` use `t.userId.Equals(userId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Caution, equals requires userID to be non-null. Use StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(str1, str2)

Comment: Or `String.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 36):

The == is overloaded on Guid so you don't need to compare the string representations.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.op_equality(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: The documentation does not explicitly state that the comparison takes care of the case. Does it do that? How can we be sure?

Comment: [Guid Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986404(v=vs.110).aspx) does support both `==` and `!=`

Answer (score 4):

I always had a dillema of using == for guid/uniqueidentifier columns comparison in linq statements (especially in where clause) so I took a rather safe route of using - (entityGuidColumn.CompareTo(guidParameter)==0) . This worked for me. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to ignore case when doing a string comparison is just convert everything to lower (or upper) case before you compare it.  So:

```
var userTasks = dc.tasks.Where(t => t.user_id.ToString().ToLower() == userId.ToString().ToLower()).ToList();
```

That being said, I agree with the other commenters that you should be using a native GUID comparison, not a string comparison.

Comment: Use `StringComparison` instead of `ToLower()`/`ToUpper()` from **stone age**

Comment: This churns through more memory (which can be a significant bottleneck depending on how much is in "tasks") and can give incorrect results depending on locale.

Comment: I knew it churned memory - I mostly work on problems where memory and compute cycles are cheap, which makes me overly lazy.  However, I hadn't appreciated that it could give incorrect results.  Thanks for the hand-slap, I'll have to learn more (as always)...