# Odata $filter query operators for guid

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have tried to filter the guid data using Odata query options. it's working fine for equal operator `/AccountSet?$filter=OwnerId/Id eq (guid'" + SystemUserId + "')` but it doesn't work for any other operator except eq & not equal.
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx][1]

what are the operators support for guid? or how can i use it for other operator.

Comment: when i'm trying to use the lessthan operator i'm getting the error The binary operator LessThan is not defined for the types 'System.Guid' and 'System.Guid'.

Comment: See: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305282/guid-type-and-greater-than-comparison-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: thanks, can i know what are the operators support guid other than equal, not equal, i have tried to use startswith it showing 'no function argumens matches for startswith' exception.