# Facing an issue with Add or Update scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying `write LINQ to Add or Update` but for me `EntityState.Modified` is not working.

Have a look at my code and let me know if you see any error.
Only new record insert works but Update does not work. 
I am using EF 6.0.

```
dbContext _context = new dbContext();            
string userName = //getting this value from somewhere else;
string userRoleNo = //getting this value from somewhere else;
Student student = new Student 
{
    userName = userName, 
    userRoleNo = userRoleNo, 
    Date = DateTime.Now 
};
bool exist = _context.Students.Any(x => x.UserId == new Guid(userId));
if (exist)
    _context.Entry(Student).State = EntityState.Modified;               
else
    _context.Students.Add(student);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: what is the value of exist? does the code fall into the else part ?

Comment: Check out this way of comparing GUIDs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725044/how-do-i-perform-a-case-insensitive-compare-of-guids-with-linq

Comment: Harry exist true, Code falls in if part. _context.Entry(Student).State = EntityState.Modified;   gets executed but does nothing in table

Comment: If the entry exsists you need to Attach() the student instance you've created. Take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: I exactly did the same as mentioned in the tutorial 'Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context'

Comment: Should _context.Entry(Student).State  be _context.Entry(student).State with no Capital letter?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified
```

and not

```
db.Entry(Student).State = EntityState.Modified
```

Answer (score 0):

Only add if it's a new student. If not, EF will track the changes for you. This way you can leave the tracking and attaching to EF.

```
dbContext _context = new dbContext();     
var student = _context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == new Guid(userId)); // Get the existing student.
bool exists = true;
if(student == null){
    student = new Student();
    exists = false;
}

string userName = //getting this value from somewhere else;
string userRoleNo = //getting this value from somewhere else;
student.userName = userName; // Do you really want to reset this?
student.userRoleNo = userRoleNo;
student.Date = DateTime.Now:

if(!exists){
    _context.Students.Add(student);
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Attach and `EntityState.Modified` is only needed when you don't fetch the item from the context. But in this case it will work to fetch the item instead.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this will be

```
using(_context = new dbContext()){    //This will dispose the context           
string userName = //getting this value from somewhere else;
string userRoleNo = //getting this value from somewhere else;
Student student = _context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == new Guid(userId));


if (student != null)
 {
   student.userName = userName; 
   student.userRoleNo = userRoleNo; 
   student.Date = DateTime.Now ;
   _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;     
 }          
 else
 {
      student = new Student () {
       userName = userName, 
       userRoleNo = userRoleNo, 
       Date = DateTime.Now 
    };
  _context.Students.Add(student);
}
_context.SaveChanges();
};
```